# Conditional multivariate gaussian distribution formula

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

The PDF of an $n$-dimensional normal random variable $x$ is:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n|\boldsymbol\Sigma|}}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}({\boldsymbol x}-{\boldsymbol \mu})^T {\boldsymbol\Sigma}^{-1}({\boldsymbol x}-{\boldsymbol \mu})
\right)$$

So, the constant that the pdf is scaled with is:

$$cte=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n|\boldsymbol\Sigma|}}$$

However, as presented in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_Kalman_filter#Kalman_filter), the pdf of $p(d|x)$ of the data $d$ conditional to the $n$-dimensional system state $x$ is $$p(d|x)\propto \exp{(-\frac{1}{2}{(d-Hx)}^T {\boldsymbol R}^{-1} (d-Hx))} $$
where $Hx$ is the mean and $\boldsymbol R$ is the covariance matrix of size $n\times n$.

I want to evaluate this pdf for a given $d$ and $x$

I found in a [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/37d5/fc70ef26169e621c16b302e9cdcadc34038c.pdf) (page 5) that the constant is equal to $$cte=\frac{1}{{((2\pi)|\boldsymbol R|)}^{\frac{n}{2}}}$$

Is it correct that in this case the cte is equal to $\frac{1}{{((2\pi)|\boldsymbol R|)}^{\frac{n}{2}}}$ and not to $\frac{1}{{({(2\pi)}^{n}|\boldsymbol R|)}^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the expression in the paper is a typo (I couldn't find a notation section to confirm that $|C_k|$ is indeed the determinant of $C_k$). You can verify it by constructing a "co-oridnate" gaussian distribution where the multivariate vector $x$ is such that its components, $x_i$'s are independent Gaussians with mean $\mu_i$ and variance $\sigma_i$. You should be able to show using this that the wikipedia expression is correct.